# MouseDrag Triangle Logic

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I'm trying to create a triangle with a simple mousedown, drag, and mouseup. I have a sketch of the logic, that I drew with lines, for further clarification and some snippet that I've been trying but, it never turns out the way I've tried to plot it out in my sketch.

Is there something I'm doing incorrect, is it not possible, and is there another solution **besides** clicking each vertex?

[image: Sketch]

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
     Vertex1 = e.Location; //First (left) Corner
    }

private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
     Vertex2.X = e.X;         //This creates a straight base from Vertex 1 to Vertex 2
     Vertex2.Y = Vertex1.Y    //'''' ''''''' ' '''''''' ''''
     Vertex3.Y = e.Y; //The y is the same height the mouse was let go
     Vertex3.X = (Vertex1.X + Vertex2.X) / 2; //The x is half way from the two corners

     Point[] pts = new Point[3] { Vertex1, Vertex3, Vertex2};
     g.DrawPolygon(Pen1, pts);
     }
```

**Vertex1 is the first left corner (mousedown)**

**Vertex2 is the right corner**

**Vertex3 is the top corner**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
Vertex3.X = (Vertex1.X - Vertex2.X) / 2; //The x is half way from the two corners
```

It should be

```
Vertex3.X = Vertex1.X + (Vertex2.X - Vertex1.X) / 2;
```

Comment: Ah, Math error. This works amazingly when making triangles that are up-straight or upside-down  but is there something else I could do for triangles that point left or right?

Comment: Sure, just slightly different math. Vertex2 would be (Vertex1.X, e.Y) - top/left, and Vertex3 could be (e.X, [halfway between Vertex1.Y and e.Y]).

Comment: Think about the rectangle described by the two mouse-event points, and where the points on that rectangle are that describe the triangle you want.

Answer (score 1):

You describe an "isosceles triangle" instead of equilateral. For Vertex3.X try adding and dividing by 2 to get the "average".

Vertex3.X = (LeftCorner.X + RightCorner.X) / 2; //The x is half way from the two corners